# What rendering engine does cfdocument use for HTML->PDF conversion?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

Simple question: Does anyone know what CF8 uses to render HTML into PDF?

More specifically, I'd like to know the version and if there's a complete description of what styles it does/doesn't support.

(for example, it doesn't support CSS page breaking - you need to use cfdocumentitem which isn't as flexible)

Comment: Thanks all - if I could accept all three answers I would, but since I can't I'll go with Leigh's answer, simply because he's got the least points at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it does use iText. CF8 uses version 1.4:

```
<cfset doc = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Document")>
<cfdump var="#doc.getVersion()#">
```

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation for the `cfdocument` tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_05.html) includes a listing of the supported CSS styles.

Comment: *slaps head* I looked at that page, don't know how I missed those. :(

Answer (score 7):

CFDOCUMENT uses ICEBrowser to render the HTML and then iText to write it to PDF.

Answer (score 5):

From what I remember, cfdocument uses [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) to generate PDFs.  I don't remember the version number, but you could open up the itext.jar and view the manifest which should contain the version.

Comment: You can download a higher version of iText and put it in the CF's lib, but I think then you need to refer to iText object with slightly different name